# Spring MVC application using Java Configuration

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Java based configuration in Spring MVC. I am trying to build a simple mvc application. But when i run the application, i am getting 404 error.

Please look into my code below

**AppInitializer.java**

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.rajumandala.securemvc"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**ElloController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ElloController {

    public ElloController() {
        System.out.println("Ello Controller");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ello(ModelMap model){
        System.out.println("in ello() method");
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello Raju");
        return "ello";
    }
}
```

**ello.jsp**

```
Greeting : ${greeting}
```

I am not understannding why i am getting 404 error when i hit `http://localhost:8285/securemvc/`

Below is my Project Directory Structure

[image]

Maybe its a silly question for you guys. But i tried a lot before posting this here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure, your port 8285 is correct ? Always default port is 8080

Comment: try "/*" instead of only "/"  for Serverlet Mapping

Comment: Hi Raju, are you using tomcat? are you using any repository tool like maven or graddle? I have test the same example in my local machine and works perfectly, so it must be a problem with /securemvc/. Just one question, is it your console printing "Ello Controller"?

Comment: I am not using maven or gradle. No console is not printing "Ello Controller". I am building this application in Spring Tool Suite and i am using pivotal tv server. To my surprise i copied the same code into eclipse and ran it on tomcat. This time i used maven. It worked. Confused.